# Wordpress - How to check whether an array is empty using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have created a PHP function for image credits, this enables users to add an image credit if needed.

An issue I am noticing with the function I have created, if the image credit field has not been populated, the background color of the image credits class is visible on the DOM.

```
<p class="image-credits"><?php if(!empty($creditsImg = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_credits', true))); echo $creditsImg ?></p>
```

is there a way i can stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has an in-built function called `empty()` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

this is good for a lot of thing, including checking empty arrays. You can use like this:

```
if (empty($array)) {
    # array is empty
}
```

or

```
if (!empty($array)) {
    # array is not empty
}
```